# Global exception handling in spring webflux during tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

I'm developing a service with spring webflux. I implemented exception handling using `@ControllerAdvice`. It works pretty well, but when I run integration tests it seems that `@ControllerAdvice` annotated component is not loaded, resulting in this response:

```
{
   "timestamp":"2019-11-28T08:56:47.285+0000",
   "path":"/fooController/bar",
   "status":500,
   "error":"Internal Server Error",
   "message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [1] in protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<it.test.model.Response> it.test.exception.ExceptionHandlerController.handleServiceException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest): No suitable resolver
}
```

This is my controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandlerController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler
    protected ResponseEntity<Response> handleServiceException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

        this.logger.error("Error occurred: \"{}\"", ex.getMessage());

        Response<Foo> response = new Response<>(new Foo(),
                "generic error",
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And this is my integration test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, MyServiceImpl.class, ExceptionHandlerController.class })
public class MyControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void testShouldFail() throws IOException {

        return this.webTestClient.get()
            .uri(uri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.statusCode").isEqualTo(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should never return HttpStatus.OK if there is an error. That is tbh poor design

Comment: and can you please remove `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, MyServiceImpl.class, ExceptionHandlerController.class })`

Comment: the meaning should be: http response 200 because the error is managed so execution has been processed successfully. The statusCode inside indicates that en error has occurred

Comment: if i remove @ContextConfiguration spring doesn't start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxTest.html) for `@WebFluxTest` it states:

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring WebFlux test that focuses
>   **only** on Spring WebFlux components.
>
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead
>   apply only configuration
>   relevant to WebFlux tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice,
>   @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, and WebFluxConfigurer
>   beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).
>
> Typically @WebFluxTest is used in combination with @MockBean or
>   @Import to create any collaborators required by your @Controller
>   beans.
>
> If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use
>   WebTestClient, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with
>   @AutoConfigureWebTestClient rather than this annotation.

This means that

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, MyServiceImpl.class, ExceptionHandlerController.class })
```

is **not** what u use here. The `@WebFluxTest` annotation does not load `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository`

It is mainly used to test RestControllers only, and their advices.

The options you have seem to be:

- loading MyController.class and then mock any dependency this class has (MyServiceImpl.class)
- load a full Context using `@SpringBootTest` instead combined with
  `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient`

Comment: The second option is working, but now to autowire the WebTestClient I have to use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) and it starts tomcat before other configuration, so it fails to connect to embedded redis. do you have any advices? If I don't use webEnvironment, autowiring fails because of no qualified bean candidate

Comment: @SpringBootTest starts an entire application, with server and everything. You need to assign it a port so that when it injects in a TestWebclient it can provide that port to the testclient. If it starts tomcat, then you must somewhere have a dependency to spring.web (the non reactive web lib from spring). If you have web on your classpath, spring will prioritize web and start tomcat instead of netty. You can force it the other way, but it is strongly recommended that if you are writing a webflux application you should not have any dependencies to spring web.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm trying to remove spring.web for 2 days but I can't figure out how to achieve this. I added this into my bruild.gradle but I think it's not working: `configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-web"
    runtime.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-webmvc"}`

Comment: i dont know gradle, if you had maven you could of run mvn dependency:tree and that would show u what pulls in spring web. You should never need to exclude spring web. You probably using some sort of library that is not meant to be used with webflux, that has not support for webflux.

Comment: spring-web is a dependency of spring-boot-starter-webflux. I can exclude it but it seems crazy, don't it?

Comment: yeah, thats crazy, so no. You sure you dont have a spring starter web included

Comment: As per documentation, ©ControllerAdvice should load, but in my case, it's not loading. Annotation used in the controller test class are ©ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
©WebFluxTest(controllers = AssetController.class)
©TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). And ©ControllerAdvice on exception handler. If I do a normal API call in bean validation I am setting 422 & getting 422, but in test, it is giving 500

Answer (score 1):

Just a not on top of the already accepted answer which is totally correct.
The usage of @ContextConfiguration is necessary only for testing Functional endpoints. I Think this is probably what confuses people.

@WebFluxTest is used during functional endpoint tests for starting the web context and server.
But since we dont use controllers, we have to use @ContextConfiguration to bring the handler and routerFunction beans in our spring context.

In this case since we use annotated controller a simple @WebFluxTest(Controller.class) is more than enough for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding controllerAdvice in the WebTestClient solved the issue.

```
WebTestClient.bindToController(controller)
        .controllerAdvice(errorControllerAdvice)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I faced this issue today. And I solved it using `@Import` annotation like below

```
@Import({MyGlobalExceptionHandler.class})
```

on top of my test class.