Controller Unit Testing with JUnit 5 and Mockito [Spring WebFlux]
I have these classes (service and controller).
And this is the unit test of the controller where I want to evaluate the case where the student exists, and as it's obvious, what arrives in the unit test of the controller is not the "ResponseEntity" but an exception.
How could I modify it to evaluate the status code (409) in the same controller? I believe that the unit test of the controller should purely receive the status codes and then evaluate if a specific one arrives, while in the service, evaluate if the model values are correct.
Controller
@PostMapping("/save")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Alumno>> saveAlumno(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<Alumno> alumno) {
    return alumno.flatMap(alum -> alumnoService.saveAlumno(alum)
            .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build())));
}

@Test
void returnHttpConflictWhenStudentExists() {
    when(alumnoService.saveAlumno(any()))
            .thenThrow(new AlumnoExistenteException("Student exists"));

    StepVerifier.create(alumnoController.saveAlumno(Mono.just(TestUtils.mockNewAlumno())))
            .expectErrorMessage("Student Exists")
            .verify();
}

Service
@Override
public Mono<Void> saveAlumno(Alumno alumno) {
    return alumnoRepository.existsById(alumno.getId())
            .flatMap(alumnoExiste -> {
                if(alumnoExiste) {
                    log.info("<<< student exists >>>");
                    return Mono.error(new AlumnoExistenteException("Student Exists"));
                }
                log.info("<<< student doesnt exist >>>");
                return alumnoRepository.save(alumno).then();
            });
}

@Test
void throwsAlumnoExistenteException() {
    when(alumnoRepository.existsById(anyString())).thenReturn(Mono.just(true));

    StepVerifier.create(alumnoService.saveAlumno(TestUtils.mockNewAlumno()))
            .expectErrorMatches(throwable -> throwable instanceof AlumnoExistenteException)
            .verify();
}


Is this what are you looking for?
StepVerifier.create(...) .expectNextMatches(response -> response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.CONFLICT))

We need a bit more details. Do your controller currently already returns 409 Conflict when an alumno already exists? If yes, please provide the code doing that mapping. If there is no such mapping, the solution might differ. Anyway this question might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085457/global-exception-handling-in-spring-webflux-during-tests
